# .Range return true when it should be false

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
   if (settingsAgeFrom > 0 && settingsAgeTo > 0)
   {
      if (!Enumerable.Range(settingsAgeFrom, settingsAgeTo).Contains(age))
      {
         canContact = false;
      } 
   }
```

This basically checks to see if age is between settingsAgeFrom and settingsAgeTo

```
settingsAgeFrom = 18
settingsAgeTo = 20
age = 26
```

should return false and set canContact to false but instead it skips over it stating its valid?

Am I missing something here?

All three variables are of type int.

Comment: you mean canContact is always false? do you have canContact initialized to true?

Comment: @tofutim yes, canContact is set to true by default, but my age isn't within range so it should set canContact to false

Comment: I would not use `Enumerable.Range()`. Simply `canContact = age >= settingsAgeFrom && age <= settingsAgeTo`

Comment: Rahul's got it I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting it wrong, [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) has second parameter as `count`, it should be:-

```
if (!Enumerable.Range(settingsAgeFrom, (settingsAgeTo - settingsAgeFrom) + 1)
               .Contains(age))
```

So by this, your range will be 18 - 20 instead of 18 - 37 (which your current code is producing).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable.Range(...) is not (from, to), but (from, count),try this:

```
if (settingsAgeFrom > 0 && settingsAgeTo > 0)
   {
      if (!Enumerable.Range(settingsAgeFrom, settingsAgeTo-settingsAgeFrom).Contains(age))
      {
         canContact = false;
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (settingsAgeFrom > 0 && settingsAgeTo > 0)
   {
      canContact = (settingsAgeFrom >= age && age <= settingsAgeTo);
   }
```